# Determine if a WebService is available or has valid url?

Tags: delphi

How can I check if a WebService is available or has a valid url?

I am using the Delphi Wizard to import and auto generate the neccessary WSDL functions.

The functions the wizard has created for me, doesn't throw an exception nor returns a null object if the WSDL or URL is wrong. Only when I call a function of the returned WSDL class, it throws an strange exception, that the XML-String has not a valid "text/html" style.

Here is the auto generated WSDL function:

```
function GetcheckVatPortType(UseWSDL: Boolean; Addr: string; HTTPRIO: THTTPRIO): checkVatPortType;
const
  defWSDL = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl';
  defURL  = 'http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService';
  defSvc  = 'checkVatService';
  defPrt  = 'checkVatPort';
var
  RIO: THTTPRIO;
begin
  Result := nil;
  if (Addr = '') then
  begin
    if UseWSDL then
      Addr := defWSDL
    else
      Addr := defURL;
  end;
  if HTTPRIO = nil then
    RIO := THTTPRIO.Create(nil)
  else
    RIO := HTTPRIO;
  try
    Result := (RIO as checkVatPortType);
    if UseWSDL then
    begin
      RIO.WSDLLocation := Addr;
      RIO.Service := defSvc;
      RIO.Port := defPrt;
    end else
      RIO.URL := Addr;
  finally
    if (Result = nil) and (HTTPRIO = nil) then
      RIO.Free;
  end;
end;

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // Namespace : urn:ec.europa.eu:taxud:vies:services:checkVat
  // Transport : http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http
  // Stil     : document
  // Verwenden von       : literal
  // Bindung   : checkVatBinding
  // Service   : checkVatService
  // Port      : checkVatPort
  // URL       : http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/services/checkVatService
  // ************************************************************************ //
  checkVatPortType = interface(IInvokable)
  ['{0F901373-2432-32E2-C99D-95B53AE83C79}']

    // Entpacken nicht möglich: 
    //     - Mehrere strenge out-Elemente gefunden
    function  checkVat(const parameters: checkVat): checkVatResponse; stdcall;

    // Entpacken nicht möglich: 
    //     - Mehrere strenge out-Elemente gefunden
    function  checkVatApprox(const parameters: checkVatApprox): checkVatApproxResponse; stdcall;
  end;
```

If the `defWSDL` or `defURL` is invalid or not available, it returns an initiaized `checkVatPortType` class/interface. Afterward calling a function (`checkVatPortType.checkVat`)  on that returned interface, I get the strange exception.

That means, if the WebService is not available the user gets a message that the "XML-String has not a valid "text/html" format". Which doesn't describe the problem.

Answer (score 3):

This is "as designed". Only calling a web service will cause network operation, and only then the network layer will fail or succeed.

Creating the web serive reference is like picking up the phone, and executing a web service method is like 'dialling'.

Update: one workaround to detect invalid URLs / non-existing servers is to use a HTTP client component (Indy, Synapse) at startup, only to do the health-check. Pass it the WSDL URL and then try to GET it. If it fails, you will know that the server is not reachable.

You can also do a GET or POST with the web service endpoint URL (for a specific service method). If you use HTTP GET, many SOAP servers will respond with an error message like "method not supported" but at least there is a response.

Comment: It would be nice if the proper error message would be thrown, instead of trying to cast the response of the function, which doesn't exist, to an xml string.

Comment: yes, this is not a helpful error message, you can submit a change request to QC